# I select all columns by some condition I want only those column will select which have some data in it

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table with 46 columns in my database, In these 46 columns 25 or 26 are mostly empty. when I select all columns by some condition I want only those column will select which have some data in it

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify exactly which columns you wan't displayed. 
There is no simple solution where mysql will display only columns that have data in them while using `SELECT * FROM TABLE;`